# Get the value of var in JSTL - Scriptlet

Tags: jsp, jstl, taglib, scriptlet

I want to call a static method in my jsp file using scriptlet and I want to get the value of variable in jstl like this :

```
<%= Utilities.splitString(${article.nommodel}); %>
```

It generates an error,

How can i get the value of ${article.nommodel} ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use 2 different ways of coding in JSP's together.

Syntax like `${obj.property}` is Expression Language syntax and cannot be mixed with Scriptlet's.

What you can do is in your scriptlet pull the variable from whatever scope its in and use that in the scriptlet:

Untested Code:

`<% 
String nommodel = ((foo.Article)pageContext.getAttribute("article")).getNommodel()); 
out.write(Utilities.splitString(nommodel));
%>`

**Of course, you should really try to avoid scriplets.  Custom Tags are a much better way to go with JSP's to give much better componentization and hence reuse of your code.**